# Android JSON - String literal is not properly closed

Tags: android, json

I'm so new to Android programming I'm trying to read a JSON String, so I created a String with `json` data as  you can see in the picture:

[image]

As you can see I get an error :`string literal isn't properly closed`

I just want to read data from this string for testing, and after working, I will replace the URL.

Comment: you need to append strings ( each line is one string ) or write in one line. sample is : "{"+ "\'Employee\' :[" + ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this method to create a JSON response object for testing purpose

```
public static String loadJSONFromAsset(String name, Context context) {
    String json = null;
    try {
        InputStream is = context.getAssets().open(name + ".json");
        int size = is.available();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
        is.read(buffer);
        is.close();
        json = new String(buffer, "UTF-8");
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
    return json;
}
```

Into this method pass the name of json that you need to create under assets folder (app/src/main/assets/) and the Context.

Example:

colors.json (Stored in assets folder)

```
[
  {
    "hex": "#EFDECD",
    "name": "Almond",
    "rgb": "(239, 222, 205)"
  },
  {
    "hex": "#CD9575",
    "name": "Antique Brass",
    "rgb": "(205, 149, 117)"
  },
]
```

Method Use:

```
String json = loadJSONFromAsset(colors.json,context);
```

Comment: dear friend i use this  code to call the function but nor esult : protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.activity_parse_json_android_example);
         String json = loadJSONFromAsset("colors.json",this);
        showMessage("jsonresult", json);
     }

Comment: another question is how i can access the field of json file i mean hex name rgb one by one?

Comment: I would suggest you to use [GSON](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Leveraging-the-Gson-Library) (`A Java serialization/deserialization library that can convert Java Objects into JSON and back`) that would ease your work.